# Added inventor to ADS accidentally, received Notice for Missing Parts for declaration

Tags: inventorship

I added a co-inventor from a previous patent to a continuation patent application. He felt he should not be named, so didn't send an oath or declaration. I forgot to remove his name, so his name was on the ADS but there was no declaration etc. So now I have a notice of missing parts to file the declaration. He's willing to sign any necessary paperwork. How should I respond? Is it the same process as change of inventorship?

Comment: You could try calling the patent office.

Comment: I assume you refer to US jurisdiction. This is a highly specialized question you are posing here. Why don't you try this forum:http://www.intelproplaw.com/ip_forum/ (US-based)

Answer (score 1):

I took @DonQuiKong's advice and called the USPTO's Pro Se assistance hotline. They advised me to simply file a corrected ADS. It's unclear if there are any fees involved other than for filing the corrected ADS.

Comment: To follow up, just the miscellaneous processing fees were required ($70 for small entity, $35 for micro-entity), since this correction was before the first office action on the merits.

Comment: As an addendum: http://www.intelproplaw.com/ip_forum/index.php?topic=28294.0 states that ADS corrections other than inventorship do not require a processing fee if filed before first action on the merits.